# Using Linear Independence to prove a set (that is not in R^n standard vector form) is a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to prove from the definition of linear independence that a set of vectors form a basis. However, the set of vectors will not be from R^n in standard vector form. How would I do this?

I know that linear independence means that there is only the trivial solution for the linear combination of the vectors. I'm confused about how to prove this if the vectors are not in R^n. I was thinking that if the vectors form the basis for a polynomial, I could form a matrix with the equations and show that each column is linearly independent, but I'm not sure if this is right. Thank you!

Comment: Any scenario in which you wish to prove that a set is a basis for a finite dimensional vector space (*regardless of if it is for $\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^{n\times m}, \Bbb P_n$, or any other arbitrary vector space*), you need to show that the set is linearly independent and spans the entirety of the space.  Alternatively, if you know the dimension of the space you wish to span, you may skip the second part of showing it spans the entire space and instead show that there are as many vectors in your basis as the dimension of the space to get that for free (*you still need to show linear independence*).

Answer (score 0):

All n- dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic to R^n.  So if you have a finite dimensional vector space, the only thing you need is to find maximal set of linearly independent vectors, and then by the statement it is isomorphic to $R^n$ and can be considered as complete set of basis.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to show the linear independence of vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m$ in some vector space $V$, you need to show that if $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m$ are any scalars and we have
$$a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_m v_m = 0,$$
then all the scalars $a_1, \dots, a_m$ must be zero.

Your question is what this means in a vector space $V$ that is less familiar than $\mathbf{R}^n$. To do this, you must be sure to keep in mind what the operations $+$ (addition of vectors) and $\cdot$ (multiplication of a vector by a scalar) mean in the specific vector space $V$, as well as what the zero vector on the right side of the equation means in that vector space.

Here is an example that may be instructive. Let $V$ be the space of all functions from $\mathbf{R}$ to $\mathbf{R}$. Show that the functions $f(x) = e^x, g(x) = e^{2x}$ and $h(x) = e^{4x}$ are linearly independent in $V$.

Assume therefore that there are scalars $a, b, c$ such that $af + bg + ch = 0$. What does this mean? $V$ is a space of *functions* with the usual operations $\cdot$ and $+$, so this means that the function $k(x) = ae^x + be^{2x} + ce^{4x}$ must be equal to the zero function. The zero function is the function that always takes the value zero, no matter what $x$ is. And two functions are equal when they always take the same value, no matter what $x$ is. In other words, we are assuming that
$k(x) = ae^{x} + be^{2x} + ce^{4x} = 0$
for *all* values of $x$, and we wish to show that this can never happen unless $a = b = c = 0$.

Now that we have translated the equation into a concrete statement, the real math begins, and if the problem is difficult, it may take some thought.

One way to do solve our problem is to write $\lim_{x \to +\infty}e^{-4x}k(x) = \lim_{x \to + \infty} (ae^{-3x} + be^{-2x} + c) = c$. If we really do have $k(x) = 0$ for all values of $x$, as we are assuming, then it is clear that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}e^{-4x}k(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} 0 = 0$. Thus $c = 0$.

Now we know that $k(x) = ae^x + be^{2x}$ for all $x$, and we can use similar arguments to show first that $b = 0$, and next that $a = 0$.

Since we've proved that the equation $af + bg + ch = 0$ in $V$ entails $a = b = c = 0$, we conclude that the vectors $f, g, h$ are linearly independent in $V$.

This example used a space of functions, which is one of the most common examples of vector spaces that are not $\mathbf{R}^n$ or a subspace of it. To translate the initial statement into a concrete one, we needed to keep the following facts in mind.

1. Given a function $f$ and a scalar $a$, the function $af$ is defined by $(af)(x) = af(x)$. In our example, we had $(af)(x) = af(x) = ae^x$.
2. Given two functions $f$ and $g$, we define $f + g$ by $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. In our example, we had $(af)(x) = ae^x, (bg)(x) = be^{2x}, (ch)(x) = ce^{4x}$, so 
   $$(af + bg + ch)(x) = (af)(x) + (bg)(x) + (ch)(x) = ae^{x} + be^{2x} + ce^{4x}.$$
3. The zero function is the function $\mathbf{0}$ defined by $\mathbf{0}(x) = 0$.
4. Two functions are equal when they take the same value for all values of $x$.

For a different vector space, the details will possibly be different, but you will similarly have to think about the meaning of $+$, $\cdot$, $0$ and $=$ in that particular vector space.